# Adding ints together from an input file

Tags: c++, input, ifstream

I have a code which looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Bill{
    std::string name;
    int bill_value;
};

enum Status{abnorm, norm};

bool read(std::ifstream &f, Bill &e, Status &st);


int main()
{
    std::ifstream x("inp.txt");
    if (x.fail() ) {
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    Bill dx;
    Status sx;
    int s = 0;
    while(read(x,dx,sx)) {
        s += dx.bill_value;
    }

    std::cout << "Today income: " << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

bool read(std::ifstream &f, Bill &e, Status &st){
    std::string line;
    getline(f,line);
    if (!f.fail() && line!="") {
        st = norm;
        std::istringstream in(line);
        in >> e.name;

        std::string product;
        int value;
        e.bill_value= 0;
        while( in >> product >> value) e.bill_value+= value;
    }
    else st=abnorm;

    return norm==st;
}
```

The input file called `inp.txt` and looks like this:

```
Joe tv 1200 mouse 50000
Peter glass 8000
Harry mouse 8200 usb 8000 headphones 98900
David book 500 800 mouspad 900
Liam phone 8000 cooler 3000 headphones 3000
Daniel laptop 700 pot 9000
```

The first is always the name of the customer, which follows by the product(s) he bought and its value.

For example Peter bought a glass for 8000, but David bought 2 books in two differente price.

And this is where my problem comes, because at David's line the program only return the value of the first book, and not the sum of the line, and i would like to know how much profit the shop made so i would need to calculate the sum of David's bill also.

Comment: Use ifstream.getLine() to read an entire line and then on that line, separate it on spaces, read the first  variable in String variables and then run a loop to read into an String variable and then an int variable and continue looping until you reach the end of the line.

Comment: Here's how it works round here. You show us the code you have tried so far. This shows you've made some effort and it helps us understand exactly what part you are stuck on, so you will get better help. At the moment it just sounds like you are expecting us to do your homework for you.

Comment: To me the tricky part is not the reading but figuring out whether what you have read is a price or an item or a person's name. I could explain that but how do I know that's what you're stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

Let `file` be

```
std::ifstream file;
```

Now, the following should work, the result is contained in `accu`:

```
int accu = 0;
for (std::string line; std::getline(file,line);)
{
    // replace non-spaces and non-digits by nothing
    // thus only spaces and digits are left
    std::string numbers = std::regex_replace(line, std::regex(R"([^\\d])"), "");

    std::stringstream ss(numbers);
    for (int price; ss >> price;)
    {
        accu += price;
    }
}
```

First we read the file line-by-line.
For each line we strip the non-numeric characters but not spaces as we need them to separate numbers. Using a `std::stringstream` we extract the given numbers.
Additionally, I made use of

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
```

Version `c++11` should be sufficient.

Note: whenever names or words contain other digits or numbers, the result is obviously incorrect. One could extend the regex to dismiss digits within other words to fix this partially. Otherwise, more information about the file structure is needed.